# Marathon-lb rules for different paths

Tags: haproxy, marathon, dcos

My marathon-lb configuration:

```
"labels": {
    "HAPROXY_GROUP": "external",
    "HAPROXY_0_VHOST": "test.com",
    "HAPROXY_0_MODE": "http"
  }
```

I want it route only requests like `test.com/12345` to internal endpoint
`/results?q=123`. How to achieve that?

P.S. Nginx rule for the same purpose looks like:

```
location ~* /[\w\-]+?$ {
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8094;
         rewrite ^/([\w\-]+?)$ //results?q=$1? break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably know marathon-lb is HAProxy plus some wrappers. You can add a redirect to [HAProxy configuration](https://www.haproxy.com/doc/aloha/7.0/haproxy/http_rewriting.html), by using HAPROXY_0_BACKEND_HTTP_OPTIONS label. There's a legacy reqrep statement which you may find convenient and you can also go for 301 redirect. For example you can do:

`"HAPROXY_0_BACKEND_HTTP_OPTIONS": "  reqrep ^/([\w\-]+?)$ /results?q=\\1 \n",`

or

`"HAPROXY_0_BACKEND_HTTP_OPTIONS": "  acl is_foo path -i /foo \n  redirect code 301 location /bar if is_foo\n",`

Note double spaces for indent. Not that you'll have to play with escapes to make it work.

Comment: It looks impossible to configure/learn haproxy/acl syntax in one evening, so I set up extra nginx router.